# Expressing Permutation as a product of disjoint cycles and transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given this:

\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 2& 3& 4&5&6\\ 
 2& 4& 1& 5&6&3 
\end{pmatrix}

How would you express as a product of disjoint cycles and transpositions? I believe disjoint cycle would be (1 2)(2 4) but Im having trouble finding how to express as a product of transpositions?

Comment: 1 goes to 2 2 goes to 4 4 goes to 5 5 goes to 6 6 goes to 3 3 goes to 1 thats one big cycle(124563) transposition are two cycles think about how you can do that

Comment: Do you want a product of disjoint cycles and _then_, separately, a product of transpositions? Or a single product of disjoint [cycles and transpositions]? Either of these seems to be a reasonable interpretation of your question (if one imagines someone who doesn't like calling a transposition a 2-cycle).

Answer (score 2):

As for the disjoint cycle, first pick any element in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. For simplicity, we'll pick $1$. So we'll start our cycle by writing,
$$(1$$

Now, we see what element $1$ gets sent to. We look for $1$ in the top row and see that $2$ is the corresponding element in the bottom row, so $1 \to 2$, so continuing our cycle,
$$(12$$

Next, we look for $2$ in the top row and see that $4$ is the corresponding element in the bottom row, so $2 \to 4$, thus our cycle so far is,
$$(124$$

Then just keeping continuing in this fashion until we run into an element we've already seen. Notice that $4 \to 5, 5 \to 6, 6 \to 3$ so our cycle is,
$$(124563$$

Since $3 \to 1$ and $1$ is already in the cycle, that is our cue to end the cycle at $3$,
$$(124563)$$

Notice that we've exhausted all the elements in the permutation, so we're done. If we weren't done, we'd just pick an element not yet in any of our cycles, and start again using the same process.

As for transpositions, notice that each transposition is a two-cycle, or in other words, a "swap". So you can think of writing a product of transpositions as the sequence of swaps you need to make to rearrange the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ as $2, 4, 1, 5, 6, 3$.

Comment: Thanks for the great clarification. Will the transposition be (124563)=(12)(24)(45)(56)(63)(124563)=(12)(24)(45)(56)(63)?

Comment: The first and last part of that equality is correct (as for David Hill's answer), but not the middle.

Comment: I'm still confused. How would you determine the middle then?

Comment: If I let $\pi = (124563)$ and $\phi = (12)(24)(45)(56)$, then the first equality is suggesting that $\pi = \phi \cdot \pi$. This can only be the case if $\phi$ is the identity permutation which it is clearly not.

Comment: Yea. I'm still  a bit confused. I feel that it could be (1 2)(2 4)(4 5)(5 6)(6 3)(3 1) but you said the middle part was incorrect.

Comment: I am saying that $(124563) = (12)(24)(45)(56)(63)$, but neither of those two are equal to $(12)(24)(45)(56)(63)(124563)$.

Comment: understand, but for the context of this question, do you need to find (12)(24)(45)(56)(63)(124563) or does (124563)=(12)(24)(45)(56)(63) suffice?

Comment: Given the description of the problem and the most straightforward interpretation, I would say that $(124563)$ and $(12)(24)(45)(56)(63)$ suffices (and they are equal since they represent the same permutation).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help to reorder the columns as follows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6\\2&4&1&5&6&3\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1&2&4&5&6&3\\2&4&5&6&3&1\end{pmatrix}=(124563)$$

Comment: So all you need to do is reoder and the product of transpositions is just (124563)? Is the disjoint cycle (1 2)(2 4)? Makes sense now.

Comment: No, your pair of transpositions is not disjoint and is not equal to the permutation. Do you understand how I reordered the columns?

Comment: Yes, I get that now. so transpositions (1 2)(2 4)(4 5)(5 6)(6 3)(3 1)?

Comment: Yes, now multiply out the transpositions to get the cycle in my post.

Comment: just to clarify, and to make sure I understand, the disjoint is (1 2 4 5 6 3) and the transpositions are ( 1 2) (2 4) (4 5) (5 6) (6 3)(3 1)?

Comment: You may write the cycle as a product of transpositions: $(124563)=(12)(24)(45)(56)(63)$. These transpositions are not disjoint (they have entries in common).

Comment: Doesn't that product of transpositions send $1 \to 1$?

Comment: @benguin you're right! I didn't take care to notice the extra transposition at the end. I've edited.

Comment: Ah, so the product of transposition and disjoint cycles go hand in hand?

Comment: they are two different representations of the same permutation. Note however that you included one too many transpositions above.